# preg_match alphanumeric and hyphens only

Tags: php, preg-match, alphanumeric

I'm trying to see if a string contains only alphanumeric characters or hyphens

Right now I have this code to check for alphanumeric

```
if (ctype_alnum($string)) {
    //do something
}
```

and have tried preg_match, but cant find the right pattern:

```
preg_match('/[^a-z\-0-9]/i', $string)
```

How can I check if a string contains only alphanumeric characters or hyphens? I have troved the web for a solution but can't find this specific case and am not very good with regex/preg_match

Comment: remove the `^` from what you tried because that means "negation" when it's within `[]`

Comment: thanks - this still allows me to use characters like . $ and @ though

Comment: @devManMan Oops. I just missed the +. It should be `/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i`